# SQL: Subtract values within same column based on two different dates

Tags: sql, case

I have a table as below, and I would like to subtract the values within column 'Price', based on the different dates. After subtracting them, I intend just to use the first set of datetime

Table before subtraction

| DataType | Datetime | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Price_1_2_spread | 2023-10-01 | 96.06 |
| Price_1_2_spread | 2023-10-02 | 112.82 |
| Price_1_2_spread | 2023-11-01 | 105.72 |
| Price_1_2_spread | 2023-11-02 | 130.04 |

Subtract price between, based on the same DAY but different MONTH

1. 2023-10-01 and 2023-11-01 = 96.06 - 105.72 = -9.66
2. 2023-10-02 and 2023-11-02 = 112.82 - 130.04 = -17.22

Table after subtract (expected output)

| DataType | Datetime | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Price_1_2_spread | 2023-10-01 | -9.66 |
| Price_1_2_spread | 2023-10-02 | -17.22 |

Tried to use this

```
CASE WHEN DataType = 'Price_1_2_spread' THEN ROUND(IF(Datetime BETWEEN '2023-10-01' AND '2023-10-02',Price,NULL) - IF(Datetime BETWEEN '2023-11-01' AND '2023-11-02',Price,NULL),2)
ELSE NULL
END AS Price
```

but that didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which database and/or SQL dialect are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to select whatever rows you want and join them with the row that you want to subtract.  LEFT JOIN includes rows from selectMonth where there is no matching subtractMonth, which will result in NULL when you attempt to subtract.  An INNER JOIN would filter these out.

```
SELECT selectMonth.DataType, selectMonth.Datetime, selectMonth.Price - subtractMonth.Price AS PriceDifference
FROM tablePriceSpread AS selectMonth
LEFT JOIN tablePriceSpread AS subtractMonth ON selectMonth.DataType = subtractMonth.DataType AND selectMonth.Datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, subtractMonth.Datetime)
WHERE selectMonth.DataType = 'Price_1_2_spread'
```

Here are some additional considerations.

1. There isn't always a match for the same day in the previous month (months have different number of days), so you might give some consideration as to how you want to handle this.  In the example, DATEADD will match the last day of the month multiple times.
2. You might consider naming the column something other than "Datetime" since this is already the likely datatype and also a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to use the [LEAD](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LEAD.html#GUID-0A0481F1-E98F-4535-A739-FCCA8D1B5B77) [window function](https://blog.jooq.org/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/) to get the `Price` from the "next" row having the same `DataType` and [day of month](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html#GUID-36E52BF8-945D-437D-9A3C-6860CABD210E):

```
LEAD(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY DataType, EXTRACT(DAY FROM Datetime) ORDER BY Datetime)
```

Here is a possible solution using Oracle 19c:

```
  WITH prices AS
(
    SELECT 'Price_1_2_spread' AS DataType, DATE '2023-10-01' AS Datetime, 96.06 AS Price FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Price_1_2_spread' AS DataType, DATE '2023-10-02' AS Datetime, 112.82 AS Price FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Price_1_2_spread' AS DataType, DATE '2023-11-01' AS Datetime, 105.72 AS Price FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Price_1_2_spread' AS DataType, DATE '2023-11-02' AS Datetime, 130.04 AS Price FROM dual
),
subtracted AS (
    SELECT DataType, Datetime,
        Price - LEAD(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY DataType, EXTRACT(DAY FROM Datetime) ORDER BY Datetime) AS Price
    FROM prices
)
SELECT DataType, Datetime, Price
FROM subtracted
WHERE Price IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DataType, Datetime;
```

It returns the following output:

| DataType | Datetime | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Price_1_2_spread | 2023-10-01 | -9.66 |
| Price_1_2_spread | 2023-10-02 | -17.22 |